# sed invoked with subprocess.check_output returns \x01\n

Tags: python

I have a data file that I want to run sed on.
Simplified version of the test.data file is given below

```
test.data
=============
some text SEARCH_URL = "google.com" some ending text
```

I want to extract the SEARCH_URL from this without the quotes. 
Following sed command works well on bash prompt

```
sed -n 's/^.*SEARCH_URL.*\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/p' ./test.data

Output
=============
google.com
```

But the command does not work when invoked from python script with check_output. The only output I get is a cryptic string "\x01\n"

```
geturl.py
=============
import subprocess
import re

#sed -n 's/^.*SEARCH_URL.*\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/p' test.data #works in bash

res = subprocess.check_output(["sed", "-n", 's/^.*SEARCH_URL.*\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/p', "test.data"]) print("Search URL is : ", res)
```

This prints output as

```
python geturl.py
('Search URL is : ', '\x01\n')
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) when you intend each backslash in a string literal to denote a literal backslash; otherwise the `\1` in your `'s/^.*SEARCH_URL.*\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/p'` string would be interpreted as a character of ordinal number 1, which is `'\x01`.

Change:

```
res = subprocess.check_output(["sed", "-n", 's/^.*SEARCH_URL.*\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/p', "test.data"])
```

to:

```
res = subprocess.check_output(["sed", "-n", r's/^.*SEARCH_URL.*\"\(.*\)\".*/\1/p', "test.data"])
```